# WCF Service XML Serialization

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have written a WCF Service. below is my code.

```
 [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="GetResult ")]
 public List<string> Array = new List<string>();

 public List<string> Get()
    {
        this.Array.Add("Apple");
        this.Array.Add("Orange");
        this.Array.Add("Pears");
        return this.Array;
    }
```

I need the XML response to be like this

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <GetResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <GetResult >Apple</GetResult >
        <GetResult >Orange</GetResult >
        <GetResult >Pears</GetResult >
      </GetResult>
    </GetResponse>
```

But the actual result is

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <GetResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:string>Apple</a:string>
        <a:string>Orange</a:string>
        <a:string>Pears</a:string>
      </GetResult>
    </GetResponse>
```

How to get my desired response. Please someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="")] 
public List<string> GetResult = new List<string>();
```

Happy Code!